# Redirect Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Intento crear y descargar un pdf, lo quiero hacer redireccionando a un método de mi controlador App/Http/HomeController de laravel desde un boton creado en App/Conversations/pruebas.php, estoy usando botman studio y la api de telegram, cuando el usuario interactúa con el bot (asistente virtual).

Creo botones:

```
$question->addButtons([
  Button::create('si')->value('si'),
  Button::create('no')->value('no'),
]);
```

Si la opción del usuario es " si "

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces me tendria que mandar al controlador App/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php:

```
  public function generatePDF()
{

    $data = ['title' => 'Welcome to HDTuto.com'];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', $data);

    return $pdf->download('itsolutionstuff.pdf');

}
```

estoy usando:

```
return Redirect::action('HomeController@generatePDF');
```

para instanciar el método y que realice la descarga del pdf. A pesar de no marcar error no realiza ninguna acción. Lo intente desde el navegador y ahi si funciona solo que el método se manda llamar desde routes/web.php

```
Route::get('generate-pdf','HomeController@generatePDF');
```

solo cambio la url por: /generate-pdf y hace la descarga

Les agradeceria su ayuda e ideas ya que botman studio es reciente y no hay muchas aportaciones

Comment: ¿En dónde se realiza la redirección?

Comment: En la clase conversations